# Call SCF item from command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that restores the explorer, and then it has to call ShowDesktop.scf file in order to minimize all windows in my desktop.

How can I call such file from batch? just ShowDesktop.scf doesn't do the trick.

In ShowDesktop.scf:

```
[Shell]
Command=2
IconFile=explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop
```

In clearEnv.bat:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
explorer.exe
ShowDesk.scf
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use **start**. However, I don't know why, but ShowDesktop.scf doesn't work if run via CMD. Here is the code anyway:

```
start "" ShowDesktop.scf
```

Anyway, I did find a workaround via VBS.
Put this in a blank text file and save it like "anything.vbs"

```
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    objShell.ToggleDesktop
set objShell = nothing
```

Now, in your .bat file, use this:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
explorer.exe
rem Always use the quotes with start, doesn't matter to leave it blank.
start "" anything.vbs
```

**Both files should be within the same path**. Otherwise, you will have to point the patch to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a desktop toogle, it's better to use

```
C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""cmd /c start /max %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"",0,false:close")
```

It's an analogue.